# What is the benefit of email verification?

Tags: security, web, email-verification

Is the purpose of email verification simply to stop spam? There are dozens of free email services offering disposable email, so what else could verifying emails be for?

Im not sure whether or not i should be verifying emails for new accounts.

Comment: is this not the right place to ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It:

- Prevents Mallory signing Alice up to your service without her permission (and making you a spammer).
- Prevents Bob from giving Alice access to his account by accident.
- Slows down Mallory from signing up multiple accounts

Answer (score 3):

It also helps you to verify that when sending an email the intended receiver receives it.